# What might cause gdalwarp to lose CRS information?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, docker

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663906/how-can-a-script-in-a-docker-container-give-a-different-result-when-run-with-cmd) on StackOverflow focusing on the Docker aspect of my issue, here I would like to focus on the GDAL matter.

I have a Docker container in which `gdalwarp -of GTiff in.JP2 out.tif` is executed via Python's `subprocess.run()`.

When I run the container in interactive mode, with `docker run -it <image_name> bash` and then `pyhon script.py`, I get the expected output. However, if I run the script with `docker run <image_name> python script.py`, the CRS information is missing from the output.

Below are `gdalinfo` outputs in both cases, see the missing parts in the second one.

Expected:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: file.tif
       file.XML
Size is 19771, 19771
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (16.295439814814817,48.338634259259265)
Pixel Size = (0.000004629629630,-0.000004629629630)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  METADATATYPE=DIMAP
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  16.2954398,  48.3386343) ( 16d17'43.58"E, 48d20'19.08"N)
Lower Left  (  16.2954398,  48.2471019) ( 16d17'43.58"E, 48d14'49.57"N)
Upper Right (  16.3869722,  48.3386343) ( 16d23'13.10"E, 48d20'19.08"N)
Lower Right (  16.3869722,  48.2471019) ( 16d23'13.10"E, 48d14'49.57"N)
Center      (  16.3412060,  48.2928681) ( 16d20'28.34"E, 48d17'34.32"N)
Band 1 Block=19771x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=19771x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=19771x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Blue
Band 4 Block=19771x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
```

Faulty:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: file.tif
       file.XML
Size is 19771, 19771
Origin = (48.247101851844533,16.386972222229545)
Pixel Size = (0.000004629629630,-0.000004629629630)
Metadata:
  METADATATYPE=DIMAP
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  48.2471019,  16.3869722)
Lower Left  (  48.2471019,  16.2954398)
Upper Right (  48.3386343,  16.3869722)
Lower Right (  48.3386343,  16.2954398)
Center      (  48.2928681,  16.3412060)
Band 1 Block=19771x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=19771x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=19771x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Blue
Band 4 Block=19771x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
```

I'm curious as to what might cause this loss of information.

Comment: Perhaps the latter, for some reason, does not find path to PROJ or into the coordinate system database file proj.db.

Comment: @user30184 You're right, somehow the environment variables are not the same in both cases and PROJ_LIB is not found in the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @user30184's comment, my issue was that `PROJ_LIB` was not found. Setting it to point towards `/opt/conda/share/proj` solved it.

(As to why this happened, it was because non-interactive `bash` executions do not read startup scripts like `/etc/profile`. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/816742) for details.)